# How to change logo on Newsletter subscription email template magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to change logo on Newsletter subscription email template magento2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code your newsletter template

```
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
        {{var template_styles|raw}}

        {{css file="css/email.css"}}
    </style>
</head>
</head>
<body>
{{inlinecss file="css/email-inline.css"}}
<table class="wrapper" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapper-inner" align="center">
            <table class="main" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="header">
                        <a class="logo" href="{{store url=""}}">
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/yourimagename.png"}}" alt=""  width="180"/>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="main-content">
<p class="greeting">{{trans "Thank you for subscribing to our newsletter."}}</p>
<p>{{trans "To begin receiving the newsletter, you must first confirm your subscription by clicking on the following link:"}}</p>
<p><a href="{{var subscriber.getConfirmationLink()}}">{{var subscriber.getConfirmationLink()}}</a></p>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

[image]